# How to change the value of a properity from inside a function using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am using [jquery serialscroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) on my website. In one of its JavaScript file some code looks like this:

```
var test_function;

(function( $ ){

     var $serialScroll = $.serialScroll = function( settings ){
        return $(window).serialScroll( settings );
     };         
    
    $serialScroll.defaults = {// the defaults are public and can be overriden.
        duration:1000, // how long to animate.
        axis:'x', // which of top and left should be scrolled
        event:'click', // on which event to react.
        start:0,// first element (zero-based index)
        step:1,// how many elements to scroll on each action
        lock:true,// ignore events if already animating
        cycle:true, // cycle endlessly ( constant velocity )
        constant:true // use contant speed ?
    
    };

   alert($serialScroll.defaults.step); //it will show the correct value '1'

   $serialScroll.defaults.step=3; //if i do this it will change the value of step to '3'

  test_function=function()
  {
    //but if do this then it will not change the value of step
    $serialScroll.defaults.step=4;     
  };
        
})( jQuery );
```

So now please tell how can i change the value of **step** from inside that "test_function()"?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change its value you have to call the method `test_function()`

Put an alert in this function and see

```
var test_function = function()
{

$serialScroll.defaults.step=4;
alert($serialScroll.defaults.step);
};

test_function();
```

Comment: by using this it will not change the value of the actual "Step" if you just try the same code(as written in your answer) and put the alert out side the function then it will again give the step value equal to 1

Comment: what i need is that i want to change the values of "step" which is written inside $serialScroll.defaults by using this test_function